# How to match reverse order of two vectors in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have two vectors

```
key.vec <- c("apple:ball", "ball:cat","dog:ear")

vec2 <- c("ball:apple","cat:cat","cat:ball","ball:cat","apple:ball")
```

I now want to use `key.vec` to look for items in `vec2` and get the items regardless of their order as separated by`:`.

So the result should be as shown below if I try something like this `vec2[match(key.vec,vec2)]`:

result:

```
"apple:ball", "ball:cat", "ball:apple","cat:ball"
```

Comment: Is this question resolved? Please accept an answer, if not resolved clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

Splitting all the vectors by each character and then finding frequency of each character (`key.vec`). Next finding if the same frequency of each character is present in target vector (`vec2`). This would help to handle both patterns.

```
vec2[lapply(strsplit(vec2, ""), table) %in% lapply(strsplit(key.vec, ""), table)]

#[1] "ball:apple" "cat:ball"   "ball:cat"   "apple:ball"
```

Comment: Really a nice way to do it. Thanks

Comment: @Ronak Shah Excellent

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sub` as follows:

```
full.key.vec <- c(key.vec, sub("(.*):(.*)", "\\2:\\1", key.vec))
ind <- vec2 %in% full.key.vec
vec2[ind]
```

Or in one line:

```
vec2[vec2 %in% c(key.vec, sub("(.*):(.*)", "\\2:\\1", key.vec))]
```

### Why?

`\\1` and `\\2` are so called Backreferences. They match the 1st/2nd regex group. So `(.*):(.*)` matches the string as follows: `(apple):(ball)`. So the `\\2:\\1`  becomes `\\2=ball:\\1=apple`. For more information see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html